# Java swing hide ubuntu sidebar

Tags: java, swing, sidebar

When I open JFileChooser, Ubuntu sidebar is shown on app. I want to hide it or take it to the background of the app. How to make this in java.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, unless you implement you own FileChooser component. Because when you open a FİleChooser(AWT or Swing or whatever), it is a call to the operating system. The operating system handles the file chooser window and its components/events.